# How to say, "I escape" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, verbs

Would it be "ego evado?"

If I put "evado" in Google translate for some reason it says it means "gain."

I want to be able to say things like,

> I escape in my Corolla.

and

> I escape in my Supra.

Answer (score 3):

I would say *fugio* is a better choice than *evado*.

Answer (score 0):

"I escape" is one correct translation of "evado". One can put "ego" before "evado", to stress the first person.

Comment: I sort of get the sense that while this is technically correct, it wouldn't be the normal way to say it, because a Google search doesn't come up with much. What would be the normal way to say this?

Comment: Another verb with the meaning of 'escape' is 'fugere' (fugio). It seems to be common, and less ambiguous in terms of alternative translations.